# Get all pictures from a Instagram tag

Tags: php, arrays, instagram, hashtag

```
// Gets our data
    function fetchData($url){
         $ch = curl_init();
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
         $result = curl_exec($ch);
         curl_close($ch); 
         return $result;
    }
    // Pulls and parses data.
    $result = fetchData("https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/{$tagname}/media/recent?client_id={$userid}&access_token={$accessToken}");
    $result = json_decode($result);
    $result1 = fetchData("{$result->pagination->next_url}");
    $result1 = json_decode($result1);
```

How do I combine both result into one array?
I want to make a loop, so i get all the pictures from a hashtag, so I can afterwards can sort it, because i use the picture-urls, how do I do what?

Comment: `array_merge` should work

Comment: `array_merge` isn't working because your arrays are objects. `json_decode($json, true)` will produce an array which you can use `array_merge` to combine with another array. Without the `true` flag, `json_decode` will automatically produce an object.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$result_array = array_merge($result, $result1);
```

Ref : http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Comment: I have tried array_merge, but the new array "$result_array" is empty,but the arrays aren't empty when I check separately.

Answer (score 0):

array_merge() should do the trick for your existing code.

If you're looking to implement a solution with a framework that seems to be well maintained, take a look at using the InstaPHP framework (http://instaphp.com). I used it recently for a the website of a couple who were getting married. It is really easy to implement. You will need to register to use the Instagram Developer API (http://instagram.com/developer/register/) but I guess you have probably already done so.

**Edit**

A simplified use of InstaPHP v1 (my project was a while ago) looks like the below:

```
<?php
include_once 'instaphp/instaphp.php';

function getInstragramPhotos($hash_tag) {

    //-- Get an instance of the Instaphp object
    $api = Instaphp\Instaphp::Instance();

    //-- Get the response for Popular media
    $response = $api->Tags->Recent($hash_tag);

    //-- Check if an error was returned from the API
    if (empty($response->error)) {
        foreach ($response->data as $item) {
            printf('<img class="instagram" src="%s" width="%d" height="%d" alt="%s">', $item->images->thumbnail->url, $item->images->thumbnail->width, $item->images->thumbnail->height, empty($item->caption->text) ? 'Untitled':$item->caption->text);
        }
    }
}

getInstragramPhotos('YourHashTag');
?>
```

Then in the config.xml file at the root of the instaphp folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Config>
    <Instagram>
        <Endpoint timeout="10">https://api.instagram.com</Endpoint>
        <Version>v1</Version>
        <ClientId>YOURCLIENTIDFORINSTAGRAM</ClientId>
        <ClientSecret>YOURCLIENTSECRETFORINSTAGRAM</ClientSecret>
        <Scope>comments+likes+relationships</Scope>
        <OAuthPath>/oauth/authorize/?client_id={ClientId}&amp;response_type=code&amp;redirect_uri={RedirectUri}</OAuthPath>
        <OAuthTokenPath>/oauth/access_token/</OAuthTokenPath>
    </Instagram>
    <Instaphp>
        <RedirectUri></RedirectUri>
        <CACertBundlePath></CACertBundlePath>
        <Cache Engine="File" Enabled="true">
            <Settings>
                <Setting Path="tmp/cache"/>
                <Setting TTL="+2 Minutes"/>
            </Settings>
        </Cache>
    </Instaphp>
</Config>
```

Comment: How do I get "Instaphp" to work, I have entered my data in the "InstagramTest.php" '?

Comment: I have added to my answer a simplified example from my implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `true` flag to `json_decode()` so that it returns an array rather than an object and then you need to use `array_merge()`

E.g.

```
$array1 = json_decode($json1, true);
$array2 = json_decode($json2, true);
$mergedArray = array_merge($array1, $array2);
```

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Thanks Alpinehc!
How do i make my foreach loop with arrays?.....

<?php foreach ($result->data as $post):  ?>
<div class="img"><a class="group" rel="group1" href="<?= $post->images->standard_resolution->url ?>"><img rel="group1" src="<?= $post->images->low_resolution->url ?>"></a><p><?= $post->caption->text ?></p></div>
<?php endforeach ?>

Comment: Assuming as an object the posts were in `$result->data`, this would now be written `$result["data"]` for an array. Alternatively you could just cast the array back to an object when you merge it, e.g.:
`$mergedObject = (object) array_merge($array1, $array2);`

Comment: If this has answered your question and helped you in resolving your issue, please tick the answer as solved. Thanks